# Error getting JSON property in Vue js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, vuejs2

I have encountered a strange behavior with Vue. I make an ajax call store the result (some JSON) to a Vue data property named: 'modello'.

```
{
  "lineaGialla": {
    "selected": false,
    "descrizione": "Questa è la descrizione della linea gialla",
    "servizi": [
      {"nomeServizio": "servizio1","descrizione":"descrizione servizio1","selected": false},
      {"nomeServizio": "servizio2","descrizione":"descrizione servizio2","selected": false},
      {"nomeServizio": "servizio3","descrizione":"descrizione servizio3","selected": false}
    ]
  }
}
```

In the template, when I access the data property `lineaGialla` using `{{modello.lineaGialla}}` it works, but when I try to access a nested property, such as `{{modello.lineaGialla.descrizione}}`, I get an error in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'descrizione' of undefined"

Here the ajax call.

```
var getData = function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    $.ajax({
      type:'get',
      url:'https://api.myjson.com/bins/w9xlb',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){
        resolve(response);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Here is my Vue.

```
var Metromappa = new Vue({
  el: '#metromappa',
  data: {
    modello:{}
  },
  methods:{

  },
  mounted: function(){
    var self = this;
    getData().then(function(response){
      self.modello = response;
    }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
  } 
})
```

What could it be?

Comment: Please post the render part as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is data is retrieved asynchronously, meaning your data is *not there* when Vue first renders the template. Here is the sequence of events:

1. The `created` lifecycle event is called
2. You make a request to the server for data
3. Vue lifecycle completes and Vue is *first* rendered with no data
4. Your ajax call for data completes
5. Vue re-renders

The problem here is step number 3. When you try to access the `descrizione` property in your template

```
{{modello.lineaGialla.descrizione}}
```

`lineaGialla` is `undefined` because the data is not yet retrieved from the server. So, in essence you are trying to read the `descrizione` of `undefined` and that is a javascript error.

What you should do check to make sure you *have* data before you try to access properties on data that may not be populated immediately.

```
{{modello.lineaGialla && modello.lineaGialla.descrizione}}
```

Alternately, if this interpolation is in some element, you can prevent the element from rendering until there is data.

```
<div v-if="modello.lineaGialla">
    {{modello.lineaGialla.descrizione}}
</div>
```

What both of these are doing is checking to make sure that `lineaGialla` is a non [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value. If it is, then it renders the data.

The reason you are OK when you render `{{modello.lineaGialla}}` is because Vue will just render nothing. The problem is when you try to *access a property* of an `undefined` value. That will blow up every time.