# vue js is possible using v-for inside custom component template?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I found nothing around the web. What I was wondering is if it is possible to use the `v-for` directive inside the template of a custom component. Here is what I have done:

**HTML**

```
        <div id="macroservizi" class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 collapse" v-if="modello">
           <lista-servizi :servizi="modello"></lista-servizi>
        </div>
```

**CUSTOM COMPONENT**

```
Vue.component('lista-servizi', {
template:
                '<div id="tuttiGialla" class="collapse">'+
                    '<template class="servizioInlista">'+
                        '<div class="row" v-for="(single,index) in servizi.lineaGialla.servizi" :key="single.nomeServizio">'+
                            '<div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-8 nopadding">'+
                                '<h4 class="blu">{{single.nomeServizio}} {{index}}</h4>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4>"'+
                                '<span class="pull-right nomargin" v-on:click="mostraServiziGiallo(index)" v-bind:class="[GiallaTutti ? \'minus\' : !GiallaTutti,\'plus\']" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="\'#singoloGialla-\'+index"></span>'+                            
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div v-bind:id="\'#singoloGialla-\'+index" class="row">'+
                            '<p>{{single.descrizione}}</p>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</template>'+
                '</div>',
 props: ['servizi'],

computed: {
    listaServizi() {
        return this.servizi
    }
}
```

I have the following errors in the console:

```
- tag <template> has no matching end tag. found in ---> <ListaServizi>

vue.js:435 [Vue warn]: Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

found in

---> <ListaServizi>
   <Root>

[Vue warn]: Property or method "single" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
```

I tried multiple ways to render it, but at this point I wonder if it is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `v-for` works fine in a custom component.

Second, there is no need to use string concatenation to build your template. Use javascript [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to wrap your template and you can use as many lines as you want.

Here I have tried to clean up your component as best I can understand it.

```
Vue.component('lista-servizi', {
  template:`
    <div>
        <div id="tuttiGialla" class="collapse">
          <template v-for="(single,index) in servizi.lineaGialla.servizi">
            <div class="row servizioInlista" 
                 :key="single.nomeServizio">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-8 nopadding">
                <h4 class="blu">{{single.nomeServizio}} {{index}}</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4>">
                <span class="pull-right nomargin" 
                      v-on:click="mostraServiziGiallo(index)" 
                      v-bind:class="[GiallaTutti ? 'minus' : 'plus']" 
                      data-toggle="collapse" 
                      data-target="'#singoloGialla-' + index">
                </span>                            
              </div>
            </div>
            <div v-bind:id="'#singoloGialla-' + index" class="row">
              <p>{{single.descrizione}}</p>
            </div>
          </template>
        </div>
    </div>  
  `,
  props: ['servizi'],
  computed: {
    listaServizi() {
      return this.servizi
    }
  },
  created(){
    console.log(this.servizi)
  }
})
```

The main issue here is you were referencing `single` and `index` in this part of the template:

```
<div v-bind:id="'#singoloGialla-' + index" class="row">
  <p>{{single.descrizione}}</p>
</div>
```

But that code was *outside* of your `v-for`. I added the `v-for` to your `template` so that that bit of the template is now in scope for the loop iteration.

Comment: thank you @Bert Evans, but if i work in this way in the console i find this message:

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: just when the template is declaring

Comment: @PdsInk What browser?

Comment: @BertEvans your template starts with `</div>`

Comment: yes, </div> is only because i copied the html part that give me problem.
Anyway i'm using chrome

Comment: @PdsInk Yes, that was my mistake. Copy the new template and see what happens.

Comment: thank you! that is a nice trick, really,  unfortunately i have the same problem as before for the v-for rendering

Comment: @PdsInk What is the data you are passing to the component? Can you give an example please? Specifically, ideally a `servizi` object.

Comment: servizi is a prop that is rendereb from 'modello' object, that i get from an asyncrunus http ajax request... well is the same object get from an answer gived by you here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605681/error-getting-json-property-in-vue-js

Comment: @PdsInk OK! See the update :) I think we have it this time.

Comment: WHOAAA! @BertEvans, i don't know how to thank you!! this is working finally!

Comment: @PdsInk Glad to hear it :)

Comment: @BertEvans you are the best!

Comment: You can also place your template between text/template tags 
<script id="template-id" type="text/template">
  -- Place your HTML code here --
</script>
That can help making things more readable